# Why did the RAE define the question mark as being an "inverted s"?

Tags: historia, puntuación, rae, dle

One of the possible origins of the question mark is show in this image [taken from the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark):

[image: Question mark evolution]

Nonetheless, the question mark symbol was defined in the *Diccionario de Autoridades* (1734) as being an inverted *s*:

> Señalase con una s vuelta del reves y un punto debaxo

The question mark then indeed was: [image: question mark]

The following editions of the dictionary until 1791 insist in this way of describing the question mark. But if the origin was a *q*, why did the RAE describe the symbol as an inverted *s*?

Was it because it was just simpler to describe the symbol that way in that state of the evolution from being a *q*? Or was it because the question mark had another origin relative to another word beginning with an *s*?

Comment: In the wikipedia link you provided the "q" theory is what they consider the less valid and it says _evidence of the actual use of the Q-over-o notation in medieval manuscripts is lacking; if anything, medieval forms of the upper component seem to be evolving **towards** the q-shape rather than **away** from it._ From this link I would say that 1734 is very late since the article mentions that it all started on the 13th century or even before that. We should look for a earlier reference then.

Comment: The [accepted theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclamation_mark) of the origen on the ! symbol looks more simple. Perhaps they simply took that and then made it curved?. This is an interesting subject I've never looked at before. Thanks Carlos for bringing it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gonzalo Correas en su *Ortografía* de 1630 [ya la describía así](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/P%C3%A1gina:Ortografia_kastellana,_nueva_i_perfeta.pdf/109):

> La interrogazion, ó pregunta, es un punto kon una esezilla buelta al rreves enzima : i sirve de mostrar, kuando se pregunta. Ké pides?

Y en el CORDE veo que [hizo lo mismo](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=1&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=220518%5C014%5CC000O22052018144755472.1184.1180&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20esezilla%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto1) cinco años antes en *Arte de la lengua española castellana*:

> La interrogazion es un punto con un rrasghillo enzima, torzido casi como una esezilla al rreves, desta forma ? Sirve de señalar quando se pregunta [...]

Fíjate que dice "casi como una esezilla". Es decir, no está *definiendo* la interrogación como una S al revés, sino que simplemente la está *describiendo* como algo que se parece a una S pequeña. De hecho, hace lo mismo con la tilde de la eñe:

> Tilde es un rrasgo corto torzido casi como una esezilla al rreves echada sobre la vocal. Desta n i tilde se conpuso la, ñe sighiente.

Es altamente probable que la RAE se limitase a hacer uso del mismo símil para la descripción oficial, por ser el más sencillo y el más cercano a la forma de este símbolo en aquel entonces.

Y digo el más cercano porque, revisando algunos documentos más antiguos, como por ejemplo [Universal vocabulario en latín y en romance](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra-visor/universal-vocabulario-en-latin-y-en-romance-tomo-ii--0/html/003fa87a-82b2-11df-acc7-002185ce6064_235.html) de Alfonso de Palencia (1490), la marca que usa para las preguntas en latín no se parece *nada* a una `q`, sino más bien a un "dos puntos" con flequillo:

[image]

Personalmente no veo yo cómo se podría haber llegado ahí desde una `q`, y de hecho y tal como ha mencionado DGaleano en los comentarios, la página de Wikipedia indica que la teoría de la Q no tiene apenas base documental.
Sin embargo, no se me hace tan descabellado imaginar que, a fuerza de escribir este símbolo a pluma, el trazo superior se fuese ligando y suavizando hasta parecerse a un punto con una tilde `.~`, lo cual sí es una de las notaciones que se mencionan en la página de Wikipedia que enlazas. Y recordemos que la tilde se describió posteriormente como una ese al revés tumbada, luego tendría sentido describir esa misma tilde en vertical como una ese al revés, sin más.

Comment: Mi móvil lo muestra bien. Con lo viejo que es, esto es equivalente a decir que es compatible con IE8.

Comment: I understand the use of long s, being a contextual variant contrasting with normal s, but the style of `ɑ` is just a font - using it seems unnecessary and hinders searchability. It's also inconsistent - e.g. you use `ɡ` where the document uses `g`, `d` instead of `ð / δ`, `k` instead of `κ` etc

Answer (score 0):

La cuestión; **¿Por qué se definió el signo de interrogación como una "s invertida"?** - Posibles esclarecimientos.

---

Personalmente creo que este tipo de cuestiones precisarían de un estudio más profundo, difícil de ser llevado aquí en términos generales.

No obstante, como pinceladas y desde mi punto de vista, la evolución histórica habría que empezar a buscarla a partir de las llamadas "**Notación Tironianas**" "Notæ tironianæ".

Las notas Tironianas *constituyen un sistema de taquigrafía inventado por Marco Tulio Tirón, ex esclavo, secretario y escriba del político, orador y filósofo romano Marco Tulio Cicerón, en el siglo i a. C.1​ El sistema de Tirón estaba formado por unos 1000 signos, ampliados posteriormente a 5000*.
[image]

*En la Europa medieval, los signos tironianos se enseñaban en los monasterios, y el sistema se extendió a unos 13000 signos, según el recuento posterior realizado en 1817 por Ultich Friedrich. El uso de los signos tironianos entró en declive a partir del s. XII, pero siguió utilizándose hasta el S. XVII*.

---

[image]

Obsérvese las distintas combinaciones, sobre todo la Q con la O y la U, donde aparecen símbolos especialmente familiares.

---

**Latín Extendido**

A parte de este tipo de escritura, cuya estructura ya de por si es importante, hay que añadir la existencia de una especie de "*Latín Extendido*", un bloque que contiene caracteres latinos para sistemas de notación y transcripción fonética, utilizado también para sonidos de la lengua Maya, representados por una serie de abreviaturas utilizadas por escribas en textos y manuscritos medievales.

---

Por otro lado, en cuanto a la letra "Q", como "S" invertida, tendríamos que retrotraernos en el tiempo para ver efectivamente que en ocasiones, según su forma escrita, puede aparecer como un "2", es decir, como una "S" invertida.

[image]

---

La letra Q en cursiva

[image]

Obviamente toda esta información debería ser convenientemente procesada para un mejor análisis, pero al menos da una pista de por donde puede ir la cuestión que se plantea.