# Are inverted question and exclamation mark supposed to be symmetrical to the "normal" counter-parts?

Tags: puntuación, escritura

Here's how inverted question mark looks like with a bunch of font I've just chosen without any particular system in my mind.

[image]

Those are very different fonts however in all of them the inverted question mark is visually very distinctive from the regular question mark. It's sort of looks bulkier as a rule of thumb.

My question would be - when it comes to typography, is reverted exclamation mark supposed to be completely symmetrical to the regular one or it differs in the majority of fonts? If what we see on the picture is completely fine, are there nevertheless some fonts where those marks are symmetrical?

Also, what about handwriting?

**UPD:** Guys I'm so stupid - like high class stupid, like very very stupid - it was indeed just bold typeface  - however even this situation you've provided some very relevant and interesting data so I won't delete this particular question - let it be a monument to my stupidity and your amiability!

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but this may be an off-topic question as it is not about the Spanish language, but about typography and concerning a symbol that happens to be used in Spanish. You should ask this same question in the User Experience site, they have a "typography" tag this question could fit in.

Comment: @Charlie In this day and age, I’d say typing Spanish in a way that respects the conventions of fluent speakers is just as important as handwriting. It’s a simple question, but I don’t think it’s unreasonable. I’d say it’s similar to asking about whether a space precedes question/exclamation marks in French, which I think is an important point. Again this is just my opinion, somewhat playing devil’s advocate.

Comment: @charlie actually, it's more on topic at graphic design SE where typography questions are on topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I see from the picture you provided is that in the picture the opening sings are kind of in **bold** font, while the rest of the sentence is not.

Question marks are supposed to be symmetrical (or being each an inverted version of the other). What you found is an oddity of that picture. If you check other posts on this site, you'll notice that there is no difference between opening and closing question/interrogation marks in Spanish.

Check the own documentation from the RAE and you'll see that nothing is mentioned about the opening question or interrogation mark being different from the closing one (except that one is the inverted version of the other: It doesn't say that they are symmetrical, but it is kind of self evident.)

> **[interrogación y exclamación (signos de)](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bH8aKhoE1D6eF5Wp4C)**
>
> 1. Los signos de interrogación (¿?) y de exclamación (¡!) sirven para representar en la escritura, respectivamente, la entonación interrogativa o exclamativa de un enunciado. Son signos dobles, pues existe un signo de apertura y otro de cierre, que deben colocarse de forma obligatoria al comienzo y al final del enunciado correspondiente; no obstante, existen casos en los que solo se usan los signos de cierre

Maybe what you found (depending on where you found it) is for learners of Spanish to notice the opening signs, and get used to them. As RAE says

> Los signos de apertura (¿ ¡) son característicos del español y no deben suprimirse por imitación de otras lenguas en las que únicamente se coloca el signo de cierre: Qué hora es? Qué alegría verte! Lo correcto es ¿Qué hora es? ¡Qué alegría verte!

What you found is definitely an oddity and not a norm.

In handwriting the same rule applies: one sign is the inverted version of the other, there's no more.

To learn more check other questions like:

- [Origin and usage of “¿” and “¡”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/137/5481)
- [Why did the RAE define the question mark as being an “inverted s”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22522/5481)

Answer (score 2):

This is a comment that won't fit into the comment box.

In support of Diego's observation that the inverted question mark seems to be in bold:

[image: various different fonts]

The first question mark seems to be a simple rotation of the ending question mark.